# How to write complex code inside the XLS file on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, heroku-postgres

index.xls.erb

```
<% @gd = GoodsDelivery.find_all_by_store_location_id(stores.id) %>
<% gd_qty = 0.00 %>
<% for goods_delivery in @gd %>
   <% gdl_qty = goods_delivery.goods_delivery_line_items.where(:product_id => prods.id).where(:customer_bill_id => nil).sum(:quantity) %>
   <% gd_qty = gd_qty + gdl_qty %><% end %>
   <td><%= gd_qty %></td>
```

I have a code something like this in index.xls.erb file due to some issues i cannot move it into the controller, But in local server it is running properly where as Heroku is my cloud there it is giving error as follows

```
Error Messege :
Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutError: Request ran for longer than 29.989883911185302 seconds.: SELECT SUM("goods_receipt_line_items"."goods_receipt_quantity") AS sum_id FROM "goods_receipt_line_items" WHERE "goods_receipt_line_items"."goods_receipt_id" = 311 AND "goods_receipt_line_items"."product_id" = 133
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1153:in `async_exec' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1153:in `exec_no_cache' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Request timeout error - looking like it's because of your slow database. Try to run your app local and connected to remote database - I think, you'll receive timeout too.